# mod_rewrite - Another simple one im sure

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Currently making a php template/framework. Now I have done as advised and put all normal files in a **PUBLIC** folder with libraries and config in others and have placed the index.php into the **public** folder but then try and do a MOD_WRITE and nothing works - Im using the Coral8 Server (For testing) and have configured it all correctly to do it but doesn't seem to be working.

Here's what I've tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^public/?$ /public/index.php
RewriteRule ^public/([^/]+)/?$ /public/index.html
```

and this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>`
```

and this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

But none seem to work :( 
Thank you in advance but someone tell me what I'm doing wrong so that I can learn from the mistake and then how to correct it.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean nothing works? Do you have .htaccess enabled in the apache config file?

Comment: all of the above keeps bringing up a 501 or 500 error

Comment: Ok can you show me the URL you want it to be and the URL it is right now? then I can see if youre mod_rewrite is correct.

Comment: ATM running local server and so the path to the index.php will be R://uniserver/www/public.index.php when live it will be relution.co.uk/public/index.html or http://relution.co.uk/?action=about sorry for being so vague this is an extremely large leaning curve for me as i'm used to old html and that's about it

Comment: just oncase it helps this is index.php been told it makes a difference as im using the **GET** command `<?php  
include("templates/header.htm");  

if (!empty($_GET['action'])) { 
    $action = $_GET['action'];  
    $action = basename($action);  
    include("templates/$action.htm");  
} else {
    include("templates/index.htm");
}

include("templates/footer.htm");`

Comment: So you want `relution.co.uk/?action=about` to be `relution.co.uk/about.html`?

Comment: yes and the main index.php is in a folder called public so when the server get a reqest it auto directs to this directory and then makes up for the messy urls as above?make sense ? cos it dont to me hahahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ /public/?action=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}$ [L]
RewriteRule ^$ /public [L]
```

So your URL will look like `relution.co.uk/about.html`

Comment: looks like it if that is the url result . . .just wanting it explained a little . . does .html and .php not make a difference . .and does this take into consideration that most files are in /public sorry for so many questions but I don't like to be given answers on a plate I like to learn from the mistakes I was makin

Comment: No the file extension doesn't matter. If you want friendly URL's to end in the common .html then you can do it the way I have it. If you want them to end in php you can just change `(.*)\.html$` to `(.*)\.php$` then the mod_rewrite will redirect the URL internally to `/public/?action=`. That will only work if your index.php is in `relution.co.uk/public`

Comment: thank you so much now i understand ur not making a rule for redirection seperatly as its allready included in the /public/? part . . .thank you for the help :)

Comment: Yes that's right. You really don't need to include index.php, since it's the index file. Does it work ok for you?

Comment: yes worked on the test server just tried it on the live server and getting a 403 error when I try to get the site on relution.co.uk but when i go to relution.co.uk/index.html works perfectly . . is there a way around this ?

Comment: yes just needed one more fix with my current coding as i'm using the get command if it doesn't pick up the index.html in the web address it doesn't get the content but from what you explained to me I just changed it to `^$ /public/index.html [L]` and then put this as the first condition so that if the server picks up on relution.co.uk it adds the public/index.html so that the second write condition collects the correct information final complete code posted below just incase . . .ONCE AGAIN THANK YOU FOR YOUR TIME AND PATIENCE @Pjack

Comment: No problem Glad you got what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /public/index.html [L]
//made addition on index.html and put it first so that it is the first rule to be applied and then makes the condition for the next rule to apply 
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ /public/?action=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}$ [L]
```